# .NET Core use dynamic route

Tags: asp.net-core, routes

I have .NET Core app.

In controller I do:

```
[ApiController]
[Route("wopi/{sitename}/[controller]")]
public class FilesController : ControllerBase
{
    public FilesController()
    {

    }

    [HttpGet("{guid}")]
    public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> CheckFileInfo(string guid, string access_token, long access_token_ttl)
    {
        return null;
    }

    [HttpGet("{guid}/contents")]
    public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> GetFile(string guid, string access_token, long access_token_ttl)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Or tried the following:

```
[ApiController]
[Route("wopi/{sitename}/[controller]")]
public class FilesController : ControllerBase
{
    public FilesController()
    {

    }

    [HttpGet("{guid}")]
    public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> CheckFileInfo(string sitename, string guid, string access_token, long access_token_ttl)
    {
        return null;
    }

    [HttpGet("{guid}/contents")]
    public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> GetFile(string sitename, string guid, string access_token, long access_token_ttl)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

When I go to the url: `domain.com/wopi/test/files/guid?access_token=any&access_token_ttl=0`
I see 404 error, what am I doing wrong? How can I resolve that issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have created a test demo according to your codes and your url is working well.

[image]

I suggest you could make sure you have the right route template and make sure there is not other middleware which will modify the path.

My controller:

```
[Route("wopi/{sitename}/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class FilesController : ControllerBase
{
    public FilesController()
    {

    }

    [HttpGet("{guid}")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> CheckFileInfo(string sitename, string guid, string access_token, long access_token_ttl)
    {
        return Ok("Success");
    }

    [HttpGet("{guid}/contents")]
    public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> GetFile(string sitename, string guid, string access_token, long access_token_ttl)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

The program.cs like below:

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.

builder.Services.AddControllers();
// Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();

app.Run();
```